Analyze the probability distribution of a specific sequence $S(x)$ with compensation mechanism
I'm developing a theoretical model for a sequence $S(x)$ equally spaced in the time dimension where each element is randomly preselected from set $\{1,2,...,L\}$, but the real selection(when it's turn) is influenced by user requests and requires a compensation mechanism to maintain statistical uniformity.$S(x)$ is generated element by element.The goal is to prove that $S(x)$ is indistinguishable from a completely randomly generated sequence $S$(By stating that the probability of the distribution of numbers at any position in $S(x)$ is the same as or indistinguishable from $S$).
Model Overview

Random generation: Each element in S(x)  is randomly preselected with an equal probability of  $\frac{1}{L}$.
User Requests: User can request a specific number at ant time, and user request sequence has a specific probability distribution, $p_i$ for number $i$,$i$ $\in$ $\{1,2,...,L\}$. User will alter the randomly preselected number(The sequence will deal with user request first and generate number ). The displaced numbers are queued for future compensation.
Compensation: After the number requested by user is generated, $S(x)$ will continue to be randomly generated, and when the number generated by the latest user request is randomized again, it will be replaced with the number that was last stored to compensate for the user request.

Additional information

User request sparsity assumption: There are at least $cL$($L=\log N + 1$) randomly generated numbers between every two user requests.
When the number requested by the user is the same as the current pre-randomized number, no compensation is required (because the statistical probability of the number will not be changed)
Under the assumption of sparsity, the probability of never hitting a certain number among cL random numbers is $(1-\frac 1L)^{cL}$ ~ $\frac 1{e^c}$ . Therefore, it can be considered that every user request will definitely be received in the next Compensation is made before the request comes.
User request probability assumption: For simplicity, we assume that the probability of user request is $p$, and thus the probability of compensation $p$, the probability of ramdom number is $1-2p$ (If the user request is consistent with the pre-generated number, it will be processed as random generation.).

What I tried
1.Probability analysis: Calculate the probability $P_j$ that any position in the sequence $S(x)$ is the number $j$, $j$ $\in$ $\{1,2,...,L\}$.The ideal situation is that $P_j=\frac 1L$(+negligible term), but unfortunately my calculation failed to obtain such
result.
2.Probability shift analysis: There are four types of events in $S(x)$ that can be considered to shift the probability distribution of $P_j$: ① This number is generated by user requset and targets $j$; ② This number is generated by user requset but doesn't target $j$; ③ This number is generated by compensation and targets $j$; ④ This number is generated by compensation but doesn't target $j$. Random nubmer generation will not influence probability distribution. However, I failed to figure out the offsets produced by these four situations on $P_j$.
Question
What statistical methods are suitable for proving that the sequence $S(x)$ maintains a uniform distribution and thus indistinguish from random sequence $S$ at any location despite user interventions and requset?
Possible solution
Markov chain with memory cL might be a feasible method. But I don't know how to calculate the stationary distribution $π$ and transition matrix $P$.
I sincerely look forward to your help!
